# ES2015+ Nested Rest explanation

Tags: javascript, destructuring, ecmascript-2016

I was checking out [node.green](http://node.green) and under **destructuring, assignment** > **nested rest**, the following example function is used:

```js
function f() {
  var a = [1, 2, 3], first, last;
  [first, ...[a[2], last]] = a;
  return first === 1 && last === 3 && (a + "") === "1,2,2";
}

console.log(f())
```

Now, I understand destructuring but I cannot figure out why how `a` was rewritten to `[1, 2, 2]`

Also `[...[a[2], last]] = a;` returns `[1, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[first, a[2], last] = a;
```

is like

```
// first == undefined,   last == undefined,   a == [1,2,3]
first = a[0];
// first == 1,           last == undefined,   a == [1,2,3]
a[2] = a[1];
// first == 1,           last == undefined,   a == [1,2,2]
last = a[2];
// first == 1,           last == 2,           a == [1,2,2]
```

---

```
[first, ...[a[2], last]] = a;
```

is like

```
// first == undefined,   last == undefined,   a == [1,2,3],   tmp == undefined
first = a[0];
// first == 1,           last == undefined,   a == [1,2,3],   tmp == undefined
tmp = [a[1], a[2]];
// first == 1,           last == undefined,   a == [1,2,3],   tmp == [2,3]
a[2] = tmp[0];
// first == 1,           last == undefined,   a == [1,2,2],   tmp == [2,3]
last = tmp[1];
// first == 1,           last == 3,           a == [1,2,2],   tmp == [2,3]
```

---

```
[...[a[2], last]] = a;
```

is like

```
// last == undefined,   a == [1,2,3],   tmp == undefined
tmp = [a[0], a[1]];
// last == undefined,   a == [1,2,3],   tmp == [1,2]
a[2] = tmp[0];
// last == undefined,   a == [1,2,1],   tmp == [1,2]
last = tmp[1];
// last == 2,           a == [1,2,1],   tmp == [1,2]
```

Comment: I guess you meant `tmp = [a[1], a[2]]` in your 2nd example, right? What precedence has the spread operator - is it the same as the bracket property accessor?

Comment: @LUH3417 Spread is not an operator, it's part of the literal syntax - like the brackets or the commas.

Comment: @LUH3417 Yes,thanks. See [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) in MDN. Property accession happens before spreading.

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean that it depends on the context, if spread is an operator (`f(...args)` vs. `[...items]`)? I just aks because it is frequently termed an [operator](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_parameter-handling.html#sec_spread-operator)

Comment: @LUH3417 [It's not an operator indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/1048572).

Answer (score 3):

In the second line, you are setting `a[2]` to whatever is the second value of `a`, i.e. `a[1]`, which in this case is `2`.

Interestingly, if you change `[first, ...[a[2], last]]` to `[first, a[2], last]`, `last` becomes 2 (the final values of `first` and `a` are the same as in your example):

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3], first, last;
[first, a[2], last] = a;

console.log(first === 1);
console.log(a + '' === '1,2,2');
console.log(last === 2);
```

It looks like `a[2]` is being assigned the value `2` first, then `last` is being assigned the value of `a[2]`. In your example, it seems the old values of `a` are being kept. I suspect this is because `...` creates an intermediate array, whose values are then being assigned to `a[2]` and `last`. Hopefully someone who knows the deep parts of the ES6 spec can confirm, but presumably that is the reason for the more convoluted `[first, ...[a[2], last]]`.

### Update

Bergi shared a spec reference in the comments:

> see [IteratorBindingInitialization](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization), with BindingRestElement. However, the usage of a BindingPattern instead of a simple BindingIdentifier is actually new in ES7. In ES6 you'd need to write var [first, ...tmp] = a; [a[2], last]] = tmp; which makes clearer what is happening.

Comment: @Bergi Could you share a link?

Comment: See [IteratorBindingInitialization](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-destructuring-binding-patterns-runtime-semantics-iteratorbindinginitialization) with `BindingRestElement`. However, the usage of a `BindingPattern` instead of a simple `BindingIdentifier` is actually [new in ES7](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#prod-BindingRestElement). In ES6 you'd need to write `var [first, ...tmp] = a; [a[2], last]] = tmp;` which makes clearer what is happening.